# how to add xmlns:tns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" to soap requests

Tags: spring-boot, web-services, soap, jaxb, soap-client

I wrote a client that calls the soap service but the requests it sends are not what I expected.

this is my code:

```
public MessageResponse traGiayToHoSo (MessageRequest request) {
        Message message = new Message();
        ThongTinXacThuc thongTinXacThuc = new ThongTinXacThuc();
        ThongTinHoSo thongTinHoSo = new ThongTinHoSo();
        FileDinhKem fileDinhKem = new FileDinhKem();

        fileDinhKem.setFileName("FvutqPDmkkC4cWjRsample.docx");
        fileDinhKem.setExtension("docx");
        fileDinhKem.setByteFile("UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQACD0AObDN+AHb0BC9/49I0+Ucq8qbBPyFxyfgjbnRFHdZGrU5P8rUqfPjZtgexsaAAAAAAAAAAAAAzkMAAGN1c3RvbVhtbC9fcmVscy9pdGVtMy54bWwucmVsc1BLBQYAAAAAFgAWALkFAADVRQAAAAA=");
        fileDinhKem.setSize("19364");

        thongTinXacThuc.setUserName("igate_eoffice");
        thongTinXacThuc.setPassWord("igate_eoffice");

        thongTinHoSo.setFileDinhKems(new FileDinhKem[]{fileDinhKem});
        thongTinHoSo.setMaHoSo("587205");

        message.setThongTinHoSo(thongTinHoSo);
        message.setThongTinXacThuc(thongTinXacThuc);

        request.setMessage(message);

        MessageResponse response = (MessageResponse) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(request);
        System.out.println(response.toString());
        return response;
    }
```

With the above code I send a request as follows:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <messageRequest>
            <message>
                <thongTinHoSo>
                    <fileDinhKems>
                        <byteFile>UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQACD0AObDN+AHb0BC9/49I0+Ucq8qbBPyFxyfgjbnRFHdZGrU5P8rUqfPjZtgexsaAAAAAAAAAAAAAzkMAAGN1c3RvbVhtbC9fcmVscy9pdGVtMy54bWwucmVsc1BLBQYAAAAAFgAWALkFAADVRQAAAAA=</byteFile>
                        <extension>docx</extension>
                        <fileName>FvutqPDmkkC4cWjRsample.docx</fileName>
                        <size>19364</size>
                    </fileDinhKems>
                    <maHoSo>587205</maHoSo>
                </thongTinHoSo>
                <thongTinXacThuc>
                    <passWord>igate_eoffice</passWord>
                    <userName>igate_eoffice</userName>
                </thongTinXacThuc>
            </message>
        </messageRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I want to add xmlns:tns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" to the SOAP-ENV:Envelope tag, what should I do?

Comment: Hard to say. A namespace declaration (xnlns:tns=...) without later use (like tns:message) doesn't make sense. I suspect that you have to add annotations to your classes (Message, ThongTinHoSo, and so on) to honor the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

try using following way:

```
import org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapEnvelope;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage;

public MessageResponse traGiayToHoSo (MessageRequest request) {
    // ... Your existing code ...

    // Create a SaajSoapMessage
    SaajSoapMessage saajSoapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(request);

    // Get the SoapEnvelope
    SoapEnvelope soapEnvelope = saajSoapMessage.getEnvelope();

    // Add the xmlns:tns namespace declaration
    soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("tns", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/");

    // Print the modified SOAP request
    System.out.println(saajSoapMessage.toString());

    // Continue with your logic
    MessageResponse response = (MessageResponse) saajSoapMessage.getPayloadSource();

    return response;
}
```

you can modify your code to add the xmlns:tns namespace declaration as I've sent.